# php report/query builder/designer

Tags: php, mysql, reporting

I am building a SAAS project where users can store information about their stores - locations, people, prices, etc. I have a few pre-made reports that users can click to run the report.

What I want to do now is give the users the ability to build their own reports. Show them available tables, which fields can be joined, grouping etc. I don't want to spend the time building this myself, I am looking for some application that will plug in to my MYSQL db and do the work for me. I googled for quite some time, but I don't think any of the results were what I was looking for.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Search on database natural language queries there should be quite a few  apps out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found something that I think will work out

http://mydbr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following solutions :

- [Smart Report Generator](http://mysqlreports.com)
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, then a good reporting engine will be [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML), it's a implementation of Jasper Reports on PHP, so your reports can be created using the iReport tool.

Comment: I checked it out, but I don't see that it can be integrated into my app. I don't want to create the reports myself, I want my users to log in to my site, and be able to create reports themselves.

Comment: I see, anyway, it could be a good start, given that it parses a JRXML file (which is just and XML file), you may be able to create a web designer for it.